# unable to understand this image read python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

my_image = mpimg.imread('mountain.png')
print('The image is:- ',type(image), 
         'dimensions is:-', image.shape)

print(image[:,:,0])
print(image[:,:,1])
print(image[:,:,2])
```

I am unable to understand what `image[:,:,0]` or `image[:,:,1]` mean ?

Comment: It fetches the *red*, *green* and *blue* channels of the image separately.

Comment: Related: ["\[:,\]" list slicing python, what does it mean?](//stackoverflow.com/q/17882205)

Comment: The canonical 'understanding slice notation' post has several answers extending this to numpy arrays, so I duped it there.

Answer (score 1):

A colour rgb image is read as a three dimensional array. The first two dimensions are x and y, and the third dimension is colour in the order red, green, blue.

The bracket notation is used to refer to subsets of this three dimensional array in the form `[x, y, c]`. A colon indicates that all values in that dimension should be selected.

Therefore `image[:,:,0]` refers to the red channel, `image[:,:,1]` to the blue channel and `image[:,:,2]` is the green channel.

Answer (score 1):

Most image representations work with a *bitmap* with an *RGB color space*. An image is seen as a *rectangle* of *pixels*, and we assign a specific color to every pixel. A color is then represented as 3-tuple: where the first item of the tuple represents the *intensity* of *red*, the second one the intensity of *green*, and the last one the intensity of *blue*. An important note is that this is *a* representation of an image: there are other ones. Like for instance using vector graphics. Furthermore there are other color-spaces as well.

This thus means that if we load an image into memory, we obtain a matrix with shape `(h, w, 3)` with `h` the *height* of the image (in pixels), and `w` the *width* of the image (again in pixels).

Now numpy allows advanced indexing: we can construct a view by using `image[:,:,0]`. This means that we construct a `(h, w)`-shaped matrix, where for an item at index `[i, j]`, we obtain the value that is placed at `[i, j, 0]` in the original image. We thus obtain an image, that only takes the intensity of the *red* channel into account.

The same holds for `image[:,:,1]` and `image[:,:,2]` where we take respecively the *green* and *blue* channel into account. The representation uses floats where `1.0` means *maximum* intensity, and `0.0` means *lowest intensity*. For instance if `(red, green, blue) = (1.0, 0.5, 0.0)`, this is a color that most people see as *yellow*.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem, thanks for the nice explanation